# Javascript/jQuery: does anybody already created a loading fixed div on top 100%:100% of the page with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, onload, onunload

i used sometimes a 'loading' method with the javascript onload & onunloadbody events.(*www.restaurantebarocortico.com*)

Now i'm learning jQuery, and i used the `$(document).ready` & `$(window).unload` to replace the old events, but the unload event isn't working correctly.
Does anybody knows another method to call a function on unload? And, if needed, a method to break the unload and do some effect (, i will need this to put an effect showing the loading div on unload).

the flow of the loading div:

- it appears on the top of everything (without effect) with an ajax-loader gif at the middle center.
- when document is ready, hide it with jQuery function (slow effect)
- when document/window is unloading, show it with jQuery function (slow effect again), and break for a while the event (or sleep the time of the effect).

Thanks and sorry my english :P
José Moreira

Answer (score 2):

You cannot prevent an `unload` or `beforeunload` event. If you could, people would abuse it to make tabs unclosable.

Comment: and can i make a unix sleep like function? with javascript or a function from jquery.

Comment: yes, you have right, but, if you call alert(), it can 'pause' until it stops. right?

Comment: You _can_ `alert()`, but you shouldn't. Also, there is no such thing as a sleep function in JavaScript that pauses the thread.